# Send and receive String with game center

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit

I have a problem with sending string via game center.
I am able to send everything but can't send a `NSString` or `NSArray`.

I have searched and found a lot of information through the google, but haven't found any examples which help me.

Can anyone tell me how to send and receive a `NSString` with game center?

Thanks.
George.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *yourString;
NSData *stringData = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and send it like this, for decompression on the receivers side:

```
recievedString = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[recievedData bytes]] retain];
```

Comment: I received string but I cannot use it outside of didReceiveData method.
when I call this line: NSLog(@"%@", receivedString); in ccTouchesEnded the app crashes. :(

Comment: well is receivedString an instance variable? If not, your app will crash when you try to access it in another method.

Comment: try this is in didReceiveData method after the recievedString line: NSLog(@"length = %i",receivedString.lenght). To see if the length of the string is>0

Comment: it logs receivedString content in didReceiveData method. for example if i try NSLog(@"%@", receivedString); in didReceivedData method it logs, and after this if i try NSLog(@"%@", receivedString); in CCTouchesEnded method it chrashes.

Comment: Well I don't know whats wrong? Are you using ARC, if not, are you retaining the string? Your problems seems to be out of the scope of this question

Comment: ARC? hmm. i don't know whats that. im new to ios development. and im notretaining the string. i just decleared it in .h file as NSString receivedString; and then im using it in didReceiveData method to get string from other device and then i log it CCTouchesEnded method where the app crashes.